# Set timeout on JAX-WS (weblogic)

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, weblogic

I have a JAX-WS that invokes another WS (the client has been build using JAX-WS). My goal is to set a timeout on the invocation. 
I know  that I can use:

```
BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT
BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT

public static final java.lang.String CONNECT_TIMEOUT =  "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout";
public static final java.lang.String REQUEST_TIMEOUT = "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout";
```

but these point to com.sun.xml.* classes, and according to Oracle this is considered a very bad practise because these classes are undocumented and might change or be removed.
source: [www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Can somebody point me how I can set a timeout on my invocation without violating Oracles guidelines?

Comment: Maybe Oracle should provide a standardized mechanism per the spec for us to configure this instead of just issuing caveats. Your best bet is to set the timeout directly on the instance of `java.net.URLConnection` available to your ws client.

Comment: @kolossus can you provide me more information regarding this? an example if possible?

Comment: What I'm referring to is the underlying `URLConnection` object that the service client stubs will eventually use to initiate the HTTP connection to the webservice. But after extensive research, it doesn't look like the object is exposed at any point. It's all buried within the API (in the `Stub` class most likely) and you won't have access to it. Beside that, it's also in the `com.sun.xxx` package so even if you could get your hands on it, it won't solve your original requirement

Comment: Oracle's recommendation is redundant at any rate: most APIs that are built against specifications (JAX-WS, JSF etc) use the `com.sun.XXX` package naming convention specifically to indicate that they're community supported. If we're to listen to oracle, how many reference implementations are going to fall foul of their "best practice"?

Comment: Indeed you have a point. I would like to know  what oracle propose though...

Answer (score 3):

Instead you should use:

```
javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout
javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout
```

You can find some more info/examples here: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Develop_a_JAX-WS_Client_Application.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting timeout properties in your WS client which are defined at the end of this page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webserv/client.html

Comment: I believe that this instructions are referring to JAX-RPC implementation and not JAX-WS